# Are tattoos frowned upon in politics?

Tags: parties, turkey

I have tattoos on my arms which have no negative/political/ideological symbols. When I wear long sleeves (shirt, sweater, suit), they are completely invisible.

If I wanted to pursue a political career in the future (especially in a Muslim predominated country), would they cause me any trouble Or is it acceptable  since anyone other than those close to me will have no possibility of knowing that I have tattoos unless I mention them or show them?

Comment: Matters of personal opinion - some persons will find this awesome, for some it'll be bothering but no real deal breaker, some will hate it, etc... Since Turkey is leading towards being a single party dictatorship it'll depend on the politics within that party.

Comment: As a general rule of thub I'd say Tatoos wouldn't be acceptable in right wing or conservative parties, but that they would be acceptable in left wing or progressive parties. There could be exceptions, though.

Comment: @Bregalad Yes, I agree. It is basically like workplace. My current workplace does not care about any forms of body modifications, however the other companies who care about such, would request to wear covering clothing. What I am asking is, even if they are not visible (inside clothes) would they be a bother to right wing parties?

Comment: If it's invisible then nobody can guess what's under your shirt.

Comment: I think this is only really answerable using statistics. I'd recommend an answer contain such, otherwise it'll just be personal opinion/anecdote.

Comment: @PointlessSpike I researched online a bit, and found out there were about 20 people openly admitting having tattoos in the US politics. 3 presidents and some Senators/Governors. I couldn't find anything about the rest of the world. I guess people really don't find out about them.

Comment: @MertKarakaya- I was thinking more along the lines of an opinion poll. "Would you vote for a person if they had a tattoo?" It might be that such a question has been asked alongside other criteria such as religion or ethnicity. In democracies, as we've seen with Trump, being "frowned upon" by the establishment matters diddly-squat compared to what the people think.

Comment: @PointlessSpike You are absolutely correct, sir. I will look into polls.

Comment: Though Turkey has a Muslim population, it's also a rather secular society.

Comment: The Jewish deuteronomic law explicitly forbids tattoos. I have no idea whether the mulism recycled that prohibition or not.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Cultural norms might be caused by people's opinions, but they're a real and observable thing, and I think it's perfectly valid to ask about what they are.

Comment: In Saudi Arabia? Yes. At your local Hell's Angels chapter president voting BBQ? Not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on country. Some countries with Muslim majority have secular governments (e.g Turkey). In some of these countries restrictions are about *Hijab* (!) not *tattoo*. In these countries maybe there is no official ban for you, but it can have impact on the reputation (Varies based on country).
 In Some countries (e.g. Saudi Arabia), "election" is on paper. Being a politician or having high-rank post does not depend on tattoo; *To be or not to be*, a Prince, *that is the question*.
 In Some countries (e.g. Iran) this considered as rude for a politician. You wouldn't have chance to be in election. Even if you have chance, people probably do not elect you.
But you said " When I wear long sleeves they are completely invisible". There is not inquisition.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Prime Minister of Canada (Liberal) and the Senator (Conservative) that he did a charity boxing match with a few years back [have tattoos](http://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/713347050107830272/1024/10/scaletowidth#tl-713347050107830272;1043138249'). But then again.... that's Canada. It may have some impact with some people, but less and less I think. Certainly less than if you had a bunch of odd piercings in obvious places.....

I can't, however, guess as to how that plays in a predominantly Muslim country. Sorry - the general viewpoint on body art seems to be very different by region.

Comment: This question has the `Turkey` tag, so answers about Canada don't seem to be on topic

Comment: Given the OP clearly showed in his comment that he was researching globally (he provides figures on relevance in US politics and indicates difficulty in finding details on other countries but IS looking), it seemed applicable.